# Number of distinct strings reachable by at most 2 swaps

Tags: combinatorics

We're given a string $S$ with $N$ characters (the characters can be repeated). We can swap $2$ positions of two characters to obtain another string, and we can swap at most twice. How to find the number of distinct strings reachable by at most two swaps?

Comment: This is from an active contest, https://www.codechef.com/MARCH16/problems/SEATSTR2

Comment: @Arthur  This question has come up many times in the last few days; it is from a live programming competition.  It should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that the answer is exponential in nature.  A string of N characters with non-repeatable characters has exactly N factorial possibilities for distinctness.

Throwing in repeatable characters would make the answer less than N factorial (N!).

look up mathematical factorial.